# Limit of a stopping time

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stopping-times

Let $\tau$ a stopping time.

Define $$\tau_n = \frac{k+1}{2^n}, \text{ if } \frac{k}{2^n}<\tau \leq \frac{k+1}{2^n}$$.

I already checked it's a stopping time, but the teacher wrote in the notes

$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \tau_n = \tau$$

I really can't understand why it holds. As $n$ becomes larger and larger $\tau$, I would say that $\tau_n \rightarrow 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to note that for any $n$, $\tau_n \ge \tau$ and $|\tau_n -\tau| \le 2^{-n}$. By definition these hold and in the limit, we have $\tau_n \to \tau$.

On another note, i am assuming that all convergences are almost sure.

Comment: Perfect, it's clear now!